# Flutter web how to get full screen size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I'm using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` to get screen size (height in this case) of my flutter web as we do in mobile, but when I shrink chrome (aka  web browser), `MediaQuery` value is converts to shrunk screen size, what I want is fixed screen size which is equal to screen size of full screen. Can I do that ?

Thank-you

Comment: This is actually really good to know that `MediaQuery...` returns the shrunk browser window size so I can use that to build a responsive custom app bar according to the window size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html) to force the screen size if it below minimum.

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final minWidth = 800.0;
final minHeight = 600.0;

SizedBox(
  width: size.width < minWidth ? minWidth : size.width,
  height: size.height < minHeight ? minHeight : size.height,
  child: const Card(child: Text('Hello World!')),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart';

int? screenWidth = window.screen?.width;
int? screenHeight = window.screen?.height;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**